# Calculate $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx$.

Tags: integration

Calculate
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx$$
with
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-|x|} & \text{if } x \in [-\pi,0)\cup(0,\pi] \\ 0 & \text{if } x=0\end{cases}$$
Any suggepstion please?

Comment: If $x>0$, you can remove the absolute value. So, the second integral is easy to calculate. The first one is twice the second one due to the symmetry.

Comment: Note, the value at $x=0$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both problems, the value of $f(0)$ does not matter.

For the first problem, break up the interval of integration into $x\lt0$ where $-|x|=x$ and $x\gt0$ where $-|x|=-x$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{-\pi}^0 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^\pi f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^0 e^x\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^\pi e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}
$$
For the second problem, notice that for $x\gt0$, $f(x)=e^{-x}$:
$$
\int_0^\pi f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
=\int_0^\pi e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx=2\int_0^\pi f(x)dx=2\int_0^\pi e^{-x}dx=2(1-e^{-\pi})$$